# $getField equivalent in mongodb aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a use case where I need to get the value of a given field (only field name is given in string) in MongoDB aggregation,
The structure of the document is as follow,

```
{
   customer_id: '23424'
   customer_23424_value: 5000 
}
```

In Mongo Aggregation pipeline, **[$getField](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/)** operator is the perfect fit for getting the value given field name in string, like

```
    {
      $getField: {
        field: 'customer_'+"$customer_id"+'_value' // 'customer_23424_value' can be written using concatenation
      }
    }
```

The $getField operator is introduced to MongoDB starting from version 5, but my production machines are running in 4.4. Is there any valid equivalent for $getField in 4.4 or any other workaround for doing the same

Comment: Yon can construct it with $objectToArray and $arrayToObject operators

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight way to handle this situation, just for reference check the below query it is expensive in performance,

- `$objectToArray` to convert root object to array in key-value format
- `$filter` to iterate loop of above convert array
- `$concat` to create a key name by concatenating required fields
- the above process will return the filtered property
- `$let` to create a variable to store the above filtered result and return the first element value using `$first`
- `$eq` check condition the above value is equal to 5000

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            root: {
              $filter: {
                input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.k",
                    { $concat: ["customer_", "$customer_id", "_value"] }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          in: { $first: "$$root.v" }
        }
      },
      5000
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b6IggBRWDF-)